# Azure blob client set shorter timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, timeout, azure-blob-storage

I have the following code:

```
private static CloudBlobClient GetClient()
{
    var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Settings.Deployment.AzureConnectionString);
    return account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
}
```

When the blob client doesn't exist and throws `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` it takes too long (around a minute or so I believe).

How can I reduce the timeout to 5 seconds or so?

Comment: Can you please describe what you mean by "when the blob client doesn't exist"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it does not send request to Azure storage server while we just call CloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient() method to create Blob service client. It just creates a Blob service client and uses the storage information (connectionstring) that you provide to configure it. In my view, CloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient() should not cause timeout issue, perhaps another code snippet in your program causes the issue.

The source for Azure Storage Client Library is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net), and you could find source of [CreateCloudBlobClient()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/CloudStorageAccount.cs).

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates the Blob service client.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A <see cref="CloudBlobClient"/> object.</returns>

public CloudBlobClient CreateCloudBlobClient()
{
    if (this.BlobEndpoint == null)

    {

        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.BlobEndPointNotConfigured);

    }
    return new CloudBlobClient(this.BlobStorageUri, this.Credentials);
}
```